# Eclipse IDE faded when not focused

Tags: eclipse, window, ide

I just changed my OS (Ubuntu) to an SSD and this never happen before.

When I'm using the Eclipse ide, every time it loses focus it fades (when I click away for example), adding like a transparent layer over.

[image: Screenshot of a faded Eclipse window]

About my Eclipse: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Nicolas. I have edited your question and changed _blurred_ -> _faded_ intentionally, because your screenshot isn't blurry at all. All edges are perfectly crisp, but contrast is too low. [This is blurry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBC9B.png), despite contrast and colors being okay. You can leave the question like this if you wish, but it's misleading and you may not get any good answers. People who know them may never click your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update Eclipse to the last version